# How do we initialize views created at runtime inside a LinearLayout from a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, findviewbyid

I have a fragment with an empty LinearLayout. At some point a user will click an "Add" button that will trigger the appearance of another LinearLayout inside the first one:

```
// inside the onClick method...
case R.id.addPlayerButton:  addItemsToLinearLayout(mContext, 1);
```

I have the inner LinearLayout on a different xml file and it contains several views. One of these views is a delete icon whose function is to delete the row, that is, delete the inner LinearLayout.
My problem is that I get a NullPointerException when I try to initialize the delete icon, which is an ImageView in the following way from the onCreateView of the fragment:

```
//class field    private ImageView deleteRowIcon;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose_players, container, false);

        deleteRowIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteRowIcon);
        return view;
    }
```

I've read the documentation on findViewById of the class View and it says that it returns null if it doesn't find any view with that id, but then, why am I able to even write view.findViewById(R.id.deleteRowIcon) without getting a warning telling me this is not possible? IntelliJ even gives it to me as an option to choose from!

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a RecyclerView and adding items, not linearLayouts, but I don't know your situation, so for conversation sake, you will need to provide the xml that you are attempting to use for both scenarios. As for finding the delete icon, you will need to use the individual linearlayout that you are adding to call myLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.delete) and this must be after it is on the screen, so after it has been successfully inflated

Comment: Thank you @Sam . Your comment helped me solve my problem. This is the first app I'm building in my life and I'm sure there are better approaches but hopefully I will learn little by little. Thank you again.

Comment: Oh Fun! Welcome to the Android world :) No problem, research making a row_design.xml, a recyclerView in the activity_main.xml and myAdapter extends ReyclerViewAdapter to inflate each row based on an ArrayList<YourModel>.

Comment: https://www.stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-recyclerview-example here see this example, try and follow it. You really shouldn't be adding linearLayouts at run time unless you are building a very custom design app that requires some crazy stuff :)